# Continuation-passing style in Scala

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, continuation-passing

I have superficially read a couple of blog articles/Wikipedia about continuation-passing style. My high-level goal is to find a systematic technique to make any recursive function (or, if there are restrictions, being aware of them) tail-recursive. However, I have trouble articulating my thoughts and I'm not sure if what my attempts of it make any sense.

For the purpose of the example, I'll propose a simple problem. The goal is, given a sorted list of unique characters, to output all possible words made out of these characters in alphabetical order. For example, `sol("op".toList, 3)` should return `ooo,oop,opo,opp,poo,pop,ppo,ppp`.

My recursive solution is the following:

```
def sol(chars: List[Char], n: Int) = {
    def recSol(n: Int): List[List[Char]] = (chars, n) match {
        case (_  , 0) => List(Nil)
        case (Nil, _) => Nil
        case (_  , _) =>
            val tail = recSol(n - 1)
            chars.map(ch => tail.map(ch :: _)).fold(Nil)(_ ::: _)
    }
    recSol(n).map(_.mkString).mkString(",")
}
```

I did try to rewrite this by adding a function as a parameter but I did not manage to make something I was convinced to be tail-recursive. I prefer not including my attempt(s) in the question as I'm ashamed of their naiveness, so please excuse me for this.

Therefore the question is basically: how would the function above be written in CPS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def sol(chars: List[Char], n: Int) = {
  @tailrec
  def recSol(n: Int)(cont: (List[List[Char]]) => List[List[Char]]): List[List[Char]] = (chars, n) match {
    case (_  , 0) => cont(List(Nil))
    case (Nil, _) => cont(Nil)
    case (_  , _) =>
      recSol(n-1){ tail =>
        cont(chars.map(ch => tail.map(ch :: _)).fold(Nil)(_ ::: _))
      }
  }
  recSol(n)(identity).map(_.mkString).mkString(",")
}
```

Comment: Mmm yeah that does work pretty well ! I feel a bit stupid now J Anyway, that's helpful, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The first order of business in performing the CPS transform is deciding on a representation for continuations.  We can think of continuations as a suspended computation with a "hole".  When the hole is filled in with a value, the remainder of the computation can be computed.  So functions are a natural choice for representing continuations, at least for toy examples:

```
type Cont[Hole,Result] = Hole => Result
```

Here `Hole` represents the type of the hole that needs to be filled in, and `Result` represents the type of value the computation ultimately computes.

Now that we have a way to represent continuations, we can worry about the CPS transform itself.  Basically, this involves the following steps:

- The transformation is applied recursively to an expression, stopping at "trivial" expressions / function calls.  In this context, "trivial" includes functions defined by Scala (since they are not CPS-transformed, and thus do not have a continuation parameter).
- We need to add a parameter of type `Cont[Return,Result]` to each function, where `Return` is the return type of the untransformed function and `Result` is the type of the ultimate result of the computation as a whole.  This new parameter represents the current continuation.  The return type for the transformed function is also changed to `Result`.
- Every function call needs to be transformed to accommodate the new continuation parameter.  Everything *after* the call needs to be put into a continuation function, which is then added to the parameter list.

For example, a function:

```
def f(x : Int) : Int = x + 1
```

becomes:

```
def fCps[Result](x : Int)(k : Cont[Int,Result]) : Result = k(x + 1)
```

and

```
def g(x : Int) : Int = 2 * f(x)
```

becomes:

```
def gCps[Result](x : Int)(k : Cont[Int,Result]) : Result = {
  fCps(x)(y => k(2 * y))
}
```

Now gCps(5) returns (via currying) a function that represents a partial computation.  We can extract the value from this partial computation and use it by supplying a continuation function.  For example, we can use the identity function to extract the value unchanged:

```
gCps(5)(x => x)
// 12
```

Or, we can print it by using `println` instead:

```
gCps(5)(println)
// prints 12
```

Applying this to your code, we obtain:

```
def solCps[Result](chars : List[Char], n : Int)(k : Cont[String, Result]) : Result = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def recSol[Result](n : Int)(k : Cont[List[List[Char]], Result]) : Result = (chars, n) match {
    case (_  , 0) => k(List(Nil))
    case (Nil, _) => k(Nil)
    case (_  , _) =>
      recSol(n - 1)(tail =>
                      k(chars.map(ch => tail.map(ch :: _)).fold(Nil)(_ ::: _)))
  }

  recSol(n)(result =>
              k(result.map(_.mkString).mkString(",")))
}
```

As you can see, although `recSol` is now tail-recursive, it comes with the cost of building a more complex continuation at each iteration.  So all we've really done is trade space on the JVM's control stack for space on the heap -- the CPS transform does not magically reduce the space complexity of an algorithm.

Also, `recSol` is only tail-recursive because the recursive call to `recSol` happens to be the first (non-trivial) expression `recSol` performs.  In general, though, recursive calls would be take place inside a continuation.  In the case where there is one recursive call, we can work around that by transforming *only* calls to the recursive function to CPS.  Even so, in general, we would still just be trading stack space for heap space.